# Como mostrar dois arrays de uma variável - PHP

Tags: php

Eu estou aprendendo a mexer com PHP e gostaria de saber como faço pra mostrar dois arrays de uma única variável.

Eu estou fazendo uma seleção do banco que me manda dois arrays, gostaria de saber como faço para mostra-los.

Na variável $res vem dois arrays, e eu gostaria de mostrar a chave e o valor. Com o foreach funciona, mas tras apenas um array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM formulario;";

$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

$exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

if ($res == false) {
   header("Location: erro.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="inserir/form-inserir.php" method="post">

        <?php foreach ($exibe as $chave => $valor) { ?>
            <h2> <?= $chave ?> </h2>
            <h4> <?= $valor ?> </h4>
        <?php } ?>

    </form>
    <form action="../index.php" method="post">
        <h1></h1>

        <input type="submit" value="Voltar ao index">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: E quais seriam os "dois arrays"? Como deseja exibir?

Comment: O código acima apresenta algum erro? Você está exibindo a chave e o valor do array associativo, teoricamente está correto.

Comment: Na variável $res vem dois arrays, e eu gostaria de mostrar a chave e o valor. Com o foreach funciona, mas tras apenas um array.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, ficou assim:

```
<?php while ($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>
     <?php foreach ($exibe as $chave => $valor) { ?>
         <h2> <?= $chave ?> </h2>
         <h4> <?= $valor ?> </h4>
     <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```